# How to define a macro that resolves to either method name or no operation?

Tags: c++, macros, c++98

In the code base I have many sections that are either turned on or off depending on enabled features. The aim is to generate program code as small as possible (Arduino with 32kB program memory).

Lets say I have the code as below:

```
class A
{
private:
#ifdef FEATURE
    int m_optA;
    int m_optB;
#endif
public:
#ifdef FEATURE
    void SetFeatureOptions(int optionA, int optionB)
    {
        m_optA = optionA;
        m_optB = optionB;
    }
#endif
};

#ifdef FEATURE
#define SETFEATUREOPTIONS(a, b) SetFeatureOptions(a, b)
#else
#define SETFEATUREOPTIONS(a, b) Noop() // ????? <-- what should I put here to perform NOOP
#endif


class B
{
public:
    A m_a;

    void DoStuff()
    {
        // approach 1:
#ifdef FEATURE
        m_a.SetFeatureOptions(1, 34);
#endif
        // approach 2:
        // Lets have a macro - see above
        // This way each time I want to call SetFeatureOptions but only when FEATURE is defined
        // I need no ifdef/endif scope to be used explicitely.
        m_a.SETFEATUREOPTIONS(1, 34);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to resolve SETFEATUREOPTIONS macro so it compiles and yet doesn't generate any code, when called as a method name?

Why way is to implement Noop() method in class A, but I was wondering if there is better way, that is not requiring adding a null method like mentioned above Noop(). I am not sure if adding inline Noop(){} will add some bytes to the program memory or not (Release, optimized code).

IMPORTANT: This has to compile with C++98 compiler.

Comment: I'd just `#define SETFEATUREOPTIONS(m_a, a, b) m_a.SetFeatureOptions(a,b)` and `#define SETFEATUREOPTIONS(m_a, a, b)` in ifdef/else branches, and then do e.g. `SETFEATUREOPTIONS(m_a, 1, 34)`

Comment: your first approach seems a lot cleaner to me. approach 2 would introduce a new macro for every function that may not exist which can get very confusing very quickly.

Comment: Approach 1 is the one I am doing now. I though, since there is plenty of such sections left and right, I could avoid it by just having oneliner macros instead. The above macro was something I do as well, but, I was just wondering if this could be done easier (less code).

Answer (score 5):

Just write:

```
    void SetFeatureOptions(int optionA, int optionB)
    {
#ifdef FEATURE
        m_optA = optionA;
        m_optB = optionB;
#endif
    }
```

and make sure you compile with optimizations turned on. Your compiler is smart enough to delete the function call, if the function is defined in the header file and is empty.

If the function is defined in a different .cpp file the compiler won't know it's empty, so it won't delete the call.

Comment: Thanks. There is only one thing I didn't mention earlier. What if optionA or any other param is not of int type but if this is enum type defined only when FEATURE is defined.
I guess enum definitions doesn't take up program space, but I wasn't aware that the params are checked for definitions prior to resolving a macro.
In other words, I cannot resolve to SETFEATUREOPTIONS(SomeFeatureEnum::Value, 23) into Noop() because SomeFeatureEnum::Value is not defined, even when it doesn't resolve into any code. Is there any way to resolve it without making sure SomeFeatureEnum is defined?

Comment: @RadekStrugalski Just define the enum all the time - I think you're overthinking it

Comment: There are some reasons I would prefer not have them (enums) defined. One is faster compile times and the second most important is that if I keep them I may not catch the places they shouldn't be used.